# Warnings displayed when using `inputAccessoryView`

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have added a custom `inputAccessoryView` with a subclassed `UITextView` inside it.

When I click on on the `inputAccessoryView`, the keyboard pushes it up and the following 2 warnings appear:

> API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7f92815391b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = > returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
>
> API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x7f92815391b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = > returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

When I move the empty `collectionView` on the view controller, the keyboard descends as the `inputAccessoryView` moves back to the bottom of the screen and then 2 more warnings are displayed:

> [View] First responder warning: 'TextInputView: 0x7f9282847000; baseClass = UITextView; frame = (10 10; 354 27); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 3}; contentSize: {158.5, 30.5}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 14, 0}>' rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy
>
> -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on > without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.

What is causing these warnings and how do I prevent them? I looked up similar questions here and none of them contain a clear answer.

As requested, the `inputAccessoryView`:

```html
class BigInputBar: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
     
     // MARK: - Subviews
     let separatorLine = SeparatorLine()
     
     // View that contains everything
     var backgroundView: UIView = {
          let view = UIView()
          view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          return view
     }()
     
     lazy var inputTextView: TextInputView = {
          let textView = TextInputView()
          textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          textView.backgroundColor = .clear
          
          return textView
     }()
     
     var sendButton: UIButton = {
          let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
          let image = UIImage.getImage(named: "chevron-right")
          button.setImage(image, for: [])
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
          button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .highlighted) //Fun develop only graphic
          button.backgroundColor = .clear
          button.isEnabled = false
          return button
     }()
     
     @objc private func sendButtonTapped(){
          print("Button Tapped")
     }
     
     // MARK: Properties
     override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
          return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: 60)
     }
     
     // MARK: - Init Methods
     convenience init() {
          self.init(frame: .zero)
     }
     
     override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          setup()
     }
     
     required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          setup()
     }
     
     func setup() {
          autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight]
          
          addSubview(backgroundView)
          addSubview(separatorLine)
          
          backgroundView.addSubview(sendButton)
          backgroundView.addSubview(inputTextView)
          
          setupConstraints()
          
          inputTextView.delegate = self
     }
     
     private func setupConstraints() {
          
          separatorLine.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          separatorLine.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          separatorLine.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          
          backgroundView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          backgroundView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorLine.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
          
          sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
          sendButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.topAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
          sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
          sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
          
          let leftTextView = inputTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.leftAnchor, constant: 10)
          let rightTextView = inputTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor, constant: -10)
          let bottomTextView = inputTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
          let topTextView = inputTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.topAnchor,constant: 10)
          
          NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leftTextView, rightTextView, bottomTextView, topTextView])
     }
     
}
```

Comment: Can you post your inputAccessoryView code.

Comment: @RaulMantilla I've posted as suggested.

Comment: same issue! any help?